# Mqtt Last Will & Testament (LWT) message - issues with the timing of the LWT message

Tags: mqtt, hivemq, mqttnet, mqtt.js

I have a `Windows Service` running on multiple boxes, and `publishing messages` to the **HiveMq Mqtt Broker**.
Good so far.

However, I noticed that when I manually STOP one of those Win Services - my browser Mqtt client **IMMEDIATELY** gets the last Last Will message (which of course I'm subscribing to).

Shouldn't I be receiving the LWT message according to the configured number of seconds in the `keepAlive` period, and not immediately ? Does it have to do with the `retained` flag perhaps ?

I feel that I have something wrong in my LWT configuration.

Here is a snippet of my C# code (in my Win Svc) -

```js
public ManagedMqttClientOptions WsSecureClientOptions(PublisherSubscriber pubSubType) {
  // Build LWT message, then Client Options
  MqttModel lastWill = new MqttModel();
  lastWill.message = "BMAZZO box is OFFLINE";
  lastWill.datestamp = DateTime.Now;
  lastWill.status = ConnectionStatus.Offline;
  LastWillMsgJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(lastWill, Formatting.Indented);

 
  clientOptionsBldr = new MqttClientOptionsBuilder()
        .WithClientId(".netWinSvc-BMAZZO-Pub")
        .WithProtocolVersion(MqttProtocolVersion.V500)
        .WithWebSocketServer("<broker-url>:8884/mqtt")
        .WithCredentials("myUser", "myPswd")                                            
        .WithCleanSession(true)
        .WithWillQualityOfServiceLevel(2)
        .WithWillTopic('myApp\myLAN\Box\BMAZZO\Status')   // LAST WILL TOPIC
        .WithWillRetain(true)                           // RETAIN
        .WithWillPayload(LastWillMsgJson)               // WILL PAYLOAD
        .WithKeepAlivePeriod(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30))         // KEEP ALIVE, 30 SECS
        .WithTls(
            new MqttClientOptionsBuilderTlsParameters()
            {
                UseTls = true,
                SslProtocol = System.Security.Authentication.SslProtocols.Tls12,
                Certificates = new List<X509Certificate2>() { x509Cert }
            });
            
    return managedClientOptions;
 }
          
 public async Task Publish(string messageIn, string topic, IManagedMqttClient pubClient = null, ConnectionStatus status = ConnectionStatus.Unknown)
    {            
        MqttModel message = new MqttModel();
        message.message = messageIn;
        message.datestamp = DateTime.Now;
        message.status = status;
        var payload = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(message, Formatting.Indented);

        var send = new MqttApplicationMessageBuilder()
            .WithTopic("myApp\myLAN\Box\BMAZZO\Status")
            .WithPayload(payload)
            .WithMessageExpiryInterval(86400)   // seconds per day
            .WithQualityOfServiceLevel(2)       // QOS
            .WithRetainFlag(true)               // retain = true
            .Build();


                applog.Debug($"Mqtt Publish() to broker - message = {messageIn} / {topic} ");
                await this.managedMqttClientPublisher.EnqueueAsync(send);
                
       await this.managedMqttClientPublisher.EnqueueAsync(send);

    }
```

Example: I stopped the Win Svc at `2023-04-25 17:30:00`, and immediately received a message in my browser that the Service was `OFFLINE` minutes earlier at `2023-04-25T17:26:43`

```
 {message: 'Offline BMAZZO 10.2.23.62', status: 1, source: 'BMAZZO', datestamp: '2023-04-25T17:26:43.7074826-04:00'}
```

Another example: I just stopped the Service at `17:58`, and the LWT message appears to show one of the previous LWT messages (retained in the broker?).

```
  {message: 'Offline BMAZZO 10.2.23.62', status: 1, source: 'BMAZZO', datestamp: '2023-04-25T17:47:32.4730311-04:00'}
```

Perhaps the `WithWillRetain` flag should be set to false ?

Any thoughts or suggestions are appreciated.

Bob

Comment: What is `mqttCleanSession` set to? (ideally remove as many variables as possible from your question and give us the real values; otherwise we need to guess). See the "non-normative comments" in [3.1.3.2.2](https://docs.oasis-open.org/mqtt/mqtt/v5.0/os/mqtt-v5.0-os.html#_Toc3901062).

Comment: thank you, I have updated my code with actual values; and yes, I have read 3.1.3.2.2. And so I would expect the LWT message to be delayed for 300 seconds (as per my code) once I manually stop my Win Service. FYI - I am always using the SAME client ID for each Mqtt Windows Service I have deployed - i.e. Client ID is tied to the name of the box - so .netWinSvc-BMAZZO-Pub will never change (using my dev box as an example). Therefore no other client would connect to the broker with that Client ID. - thank you.

Comment: Perhaps my confusion lies in the fact that I have set the `keepAlive` = `300` secs, as well as `lastWillRetain` set to `true`. And when I set the LWT `payload` message, I also add the datetime stamp - so the time portion of my LWT message doesn't represent the EXACT time that my client went offline.

Comment: I also understand that (acc. to the `3.1.2.5 Will Flag specs `at http://docs.oasis-open.org/mqtt/mqtt/v3.1.1/mqtt-v3.1.1.html) the broker will pub the LWT message when `The client fails to communicate within the defined Keep Alive period.` I do have a heartbeat message in my Win Svc code which pings the broker every N num of milliseconds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly a note - in the comments you reference the v3 spec ("3.1.2.5 Will Flag specs at docs.oasis-open.org/mqtt/mqtt/v3.1.1/mqtt-v3.1.1.html"). You are using MQTT v5 (`.WithProtocolVersion(MqttProtocolVersion.V500)`) and this is one area where the specs vary considerably. The below is based upon my understanding of the spec (so may contain errors!).

What you are seeing appears in line with the [MQTT v5 spec](https://docs.oasis-open.org/mqtt/mqtt/v5.0/os/mqtt-v5.0-os.html#_Toc3901062) which says:

> The Server delays publishing the Client’s Will Message until the Will Delay Interval has passed or the Session ends, whichever happens first

So the question here is "when does the session end"; I believe the [relevant section of the spec](https://docs.oasis-open.org/mqtt/mqtt/v5.0/os/mqtt-v5.0-os.html#_Toc3901230) is:

> The session can continue across a sequence of Network Connections. It lasts as long as the latest Network Connection plus the Session Expiry Interval.

Your code does not use the `SessionExpiryInterval()` option meaning that the session will expire [immediately upon disconnection](https://docs.oasis-open.org/mqtt/mqtt/v5.0/os/mqtt-v5.0-os.html#_Toc3901048)

> If the Session Expiry Interval is absent the value 0 is used.

So when your client disconnects the session ends and the Will is published.

With reference to keep alives; these are a mechanism to enable the client to detect a [half-open connection](https://www.hivemq.com/blog/mqtt-essentials-part-10-alive-client-take-over/).
Often (especially when a service is cleanly shutdown) the other side of the connection will be notified when the connection is closed and the keep alive is irrelevant.

Note that another factor may be coming into play (as mentioned by @Aaron Franz):

> when I manually STOP one of those Win Services

Manually stopping the services may be resulting in a clean disconnection (i.e. a DISCONNECT packet is sent). Disconnecting cleanly ("Normal disconnection")
[deletes the will](https://docs.oasis-open.org/mqtt/mqtt/v5.0/os/mqtt-v5.0-os.html#_Toc3901208) but you may also opt to send it (and this may change the session expiry interval).

*Additional comments (added later in response to comments)*

> I'm not sure that I need both SessionExpiryInterval AND WithWillDelayInterval since it will delay publishing..

Correct; `WithWillDelayInterval` is really only useful when it's less than `SessionExpiryInterval` (and really only with `WithCleanSession(false)`). The broker and client can retain session information (and messages published) while the connection is down meaning that intermittent connection loss does not result in any loss of QOS1+ messages. As such you might not be bothered by a 1 minute outage but do want to know if the connection is down more than 10 minutes (times will depend upon your use-case - e.g. `SessionExpiryInterval` = 1 month, `WithWillDelayInterval` = 10 minutes).

Comment: you're right, as I did NOT see the `WithWillDelayInterval` setter in MQTTnet using protocol `v5` (their documentation is horrible). I was also getting stuck on spec  `3.1.2.5 Will Flag` , where one of the conditions is  `The Client fails to communicate within the Keep Alive time.` So my assumption was that the `.WithKeepAlivePeriod` value would enable that delay, as long as `the interval between MQTT Control Packets being sent does not exceed the Keep Alive value.` (as per `3.1.2.10 ` in the v5 Oasis specs)

Comment: I tested it, and you're right again. Without setting the SessionExpiry, the LWT get published immediately. I'm not sure that I need both `SessionExpiryInterval` AND `WithWillDelayInterval` since it will delay publishing the LWT message based on "whichever happens first". It seems that SessionExpiry is sufficient for delaying the LWT.

Comment: What's also interesting is that if I physically disconnect the network cable from my dev box, my `DisconnectedAsync` event fires in the c# service. And the message from the `MqttClientDisconnectedEventArgs` param is `KeepAliveTimeout The client was idle for too long without sending an MQTT control packet.`. However, if I shutdown the service manually (as you had mentioned) I do NOT get hit that Disconnected method (as it appears to be `graceful` shutdown in that case).

Answer (score 1):

Glad to hear implementation stories for the HiveMQ Broker!

One detail I wanted to clarify - when this service is terminated, is there any current functionality implemented to send a DISCONNECT packet when the service has been terminated?  The current functionality seems to indicate that a graceful disconnect is being triggered at the time of connection closure.  Depending on the version of the HiveMQ broker being used, it may be worthwhile to implement a custom listener to log onDisconnect or onServerInitiatedDisconnect reason codes for more specific diagnostics.  More information regarding implementation can be found here : https://docs.hivemq.com/hivemq/4.11/extensions/registries.html#on-server-disconnect.

Also, I encourage anyone with questions regarding HiveMQ to reach out on our community forum at https://community.hivemq.com/!

Best,

Aaron from the HiveMQ Team

Comment: I do have an account there as well Aaron, and thanks for the feedback. In fact I do have a `DisconnectedAsync` event in the MQTTnet c# lib, but not currently implemented as you have suggested. In addition, I am attempting to simulate an UNGRACEFUL disconnect scenario so I will work on testing that event method today. Thank you.